# Correct place for a comma in the question: 'How can you determine where the first one is and where the second is?'

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, tag-questions, wh-questions

A student asked me if it is correct to put a comma here in this question:

> How can you determine, where the first one is and where the second is?

My instinct is that this is grammatically incorrect, and perhaps the correct sentence is:

> How can you determine where the first one is, and where the second is?

Does anyone know which is right, and why?

Answer (score 1):

> How can you determine where the first one is, and where the second is?

The comma before "and" is optional.  It is a stylistic choice.

> How can you determine, where the first one is and where the second is?

The comma before "where" is wrong.  We don't use a comma to separate the verb from its direct object - so in the same way that there is no comma in "How can you determine the answer?", there's no comma in this sentence, either.  The fact that the direct object consists of a subordinate clause makes no difference.

In non-restrictive relative clauses, "where" is usually preceded by a comma: "The Old Red Lion, where he had left his hat, was still open."